# How to get Rotation Quaternion of my android device in ARcore?

Tags: java, android, arcore

I am working on an AR project, and developping ARCorea application.
I want to use the current frame and get a rotation and translation.
Current implementation and my environment is below;

```
private Session session;

Frame frame = session.update();
Pose pose = frame.getAndroidSensorPose();

float[] t = new float[3];
float[] r = new float[4];
Pose rhspose = new Pose(t,r);
Pose thispose;

thispose = pose.compose(rhspose);

float translation[] = thispose.getTranslation();

float orientation[] = thispose.getRotationQuaternion();
```

----environment
Android Studio：Ver.4.0.1
ARCore SDK：Ver.1.18.1
Device：ASUS_A002

Following the next page, I could get collect translation vector, but not rotation vector.
The rotation vector values are always 0.
https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Pose

How do I use getRotationQuaternion() for a frame?
Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question.

```
thispose = pose.extractTranslation();
float translation[] = thispose.getTranslation();
thispose = pose.extractRotation();
float orientation[] = thispose.getRotationQuaternion();
```

Thanks.